# Check if records with same value in one column are the same throughout

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df called with ~1 million records. The df has over 80 columns, with one of those columns being asset_id. I want to create a subset of all the records which have duplicate asset_ids, but have a different value in at least one of the other columns.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"asset_id": [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5], "Name":["Canola", "Canola", "Canola", "Precision", "Precision", "Explore", "Testing", "Conda", "Conda Inc"], "Country":["CAN", "CAN", "USA", "CAN", "CAN", "USA", "CAN", "USA", "USA"]})
```

```
asset_id    Name    Country 
  1       Canola     CAN
  1       Canola     CAN
  1       Canola     USA
  2       Precision  CAN
  2       Precision  CAN
  3       Explore    USA
  4       Testing    CAN
  5       Conda      USA
  5       Conda Inc  USA
```

I would want the resulting table to look like this:

```
asset_id    Name    Country
  1       Canola     CAN
  1       Canola     USA
  5       Conda      USA
  5       Conda Inc  USA
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: so basically you want to remove full duplicate rows?

Comment: @Valentino Yes but I also want to get rid of rows with no duplicates at all, I basically want to keep all records with duplicate asset_ids and a difference in at least one other column

Answer (score 3):

You could directly filter out the groups that have more than one `Name` or more than one `Country` and then drop any remaining duplicates with:

`df.groupby('asset_id').filter(lambda x: (x.Name.nunique()>1) | (x.Country.nunique()>1)).drop_duplicates()`

Output:

```
asset_id    Name    Country
0   1   Canola  CAN
2   1   Canola  USA
7   5   Conda   USA
8   5   Conda Inc   USA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function to do the selection and use it with `groupby` and `apply`.

```
def selecting(x):
    lencol = set(len(x[col].unique()) for col in x.columns)
    if len(lencol) == 1:
        return pd.DataFrame(columns=x.columns) #empty dataframe
    else:
        return x[~x.duplicated()]

ddf = df.groupby('asset_id').apply(selecting)
```

If you drop the indexes created by `groupby` you get:

```
ddf.reset_index(drop=True)

  asset_id       Name Country
0        1     Canola     CAN
1        1     Canola     USA
2        5      Conda     USA
3        5  Conda Inc     USA
```

#### Explanation

`lencol` is a `set` storing how many unique elements has each column. Being a set, columns with same number of elements does not appear.
Hence if `len(lencol)` is 1 (the `set` has one element) an empty dataframe is returned. Otherwise, a dataframe without duplicate rows is returned. Check the [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method to undersand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `drop_duplicates()`. It gets the job done.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "asset_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
        "Name": [
            "Canola",
            "Canola",
            "Canola",
            "Precision",
            "Precision",
            "Explore",
            "Testing",
            "Conda",
            "Conda Inc",
        ],
        "Country": ["CAN", "CAN", "USA", "CAN", "CAN", "USA", "CAN", "USA", "USA"],
    }
)


df = df.drop_duplicates()
x = df["asset_id"].value_counts()
data = []
for elem, elem1 in zip(x.index, x):
    if elem1 > 1:
        y = df.loc[df["asset_id"] == elem]
        print(y.values)
```

It produces the `list` of what you wanted (the code above produces it):

```
[[5 'Conda' 'USA']
 [5 'Conda Inc' 'USA']]
[[1 'Canola' 'CAN']
 [1 'Canola' 'USA']]
```

Comment: You did not follow the requirements of OP

Comment: @Akaisteph7 fixed with my version.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 can you up vote pls? you reduced my score